# How to make a item listview equal to name in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to print a listview and when I click an item go to a new listview equal to the value in the firebase database

Example: Restaurant will show

- Guich
- Yum-Yum

When I click Guich will show

- Pizza
- Hamburgers

[Firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC0Pn.png)

```
public class RestaurantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Restaurant");
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
                areas.add(value1);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlateActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, areas);
            lv.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Error", "Something happened");
        }
    });
}

}

public class PlateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("");
private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plate);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
                areas.add(value1);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlateActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, areas);
            lv.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("Error", "Something happened");
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is capture all the keys and then when you click on the list item call the appropriate position that holds that key and value.

```
for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
    areas.add(value1);
    //areaSnapshot.getKey.toString(); add to local array (keyArray)
}
```

In your list `Listener` do something like: `keyArray.get(position)` and use this string to call the new Firebase snapshot in the new list.